# Planetary Reflectance vs Relative Spectral Response

Tags: remote-sensing

I am confused between a Planetary Reflectance and the Relative Spectral Response (RSR). What I know/guess is that RSR is a response/function of an Instrument band's reflectance against a spectral range. Isn't that reflectance the Planetary Reflectance?

I am trying to solve this problem:

> If the soil spectra was obtained at 10:20 am in January 5, 2005 at 14°
>   20’ N 121° 13’ E, compute for the spectral radiance of soil at a) sea
>   level, b) extra-terrestrial level. On this day, the Landsat ETM+
>   satellite passed over the area. Neglecting atmospheric effects, what
>   is the possible radiance detected by the sensor in the four bands?

I am given with:

1. Solar Irradiance values in a) Sea Level and b) Extra-Terrestrial Level which is also a response/function against a range of wavelength.
2. RSR for Landsat-7 ETM+
3. Spectral Signature of soil which is also a reflectance function/response against a spectral range.

Using the reference below, I need to compute for the Spectral Radiance *Lλ*.
I can use the RSR and and Solar Irradiance to compute for Mean Solar Exoatmospheric Irradiance, *Esunλ*. The Earth-Sun distance *d* has a Julian Calendar table while the Solar zenith angle *θs* can be computed using the given date and time in the question. Where can I get the Planetary Reflectance to solve this problem? Is it the reflectance for a wavelength in the RSR?

Reference:

1. [IKONOS Planetary Reflectance and Mean Solar Exoatmospheric Irradiance](https://apollomapping.com/wp-content/user_uploads/2011/09/IKONOS_Esun_Calculations.pdf)